# How integrate views in new django app

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I had django-paypal views.py:

```
    from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm

    def view_that_asks_for_money(request):

     paypal_dict = {
    "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
    "amount": "10000000.00",
    "item_name": "name of the item",
    "invoice": "unique-invoice-id",
    "notify_url": "https://www.example.com" + reverse('paypal-ipn'),
    "return_url": "https://www.example.com/your-return-location/",
    "cancel_return": "https://www.example.com/your-cancel-location/",

}

# Create the instance.
form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
context = {"form": form}
return render_to_response("payment.html", context)
```

How i must include it in my basic app example so all function will work and payment.html rendered

Answer (score 0):

The PayPalPaymentsForm should be recieved a object, not a dict.
So, you can build a objects as argument. 
for example:

```
     form = PayPalPaymentsForm()
     form.businness = paypal_dict["bussiness"]
```